# Resharper disable string completion?

Tags: c#, resharper

How do you stop resharper from adding "" when you type "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untick "Auto-insert pair brackets, parentheses and quotes":

- http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Options/editor.html